# Azure API Management IP for whitelisting

Tags: azure-api-management

I have a bunch of app services listed in API management.  These services call third party clients who want to whitelist my IP

I would like to give them the public IP address of the APIM instance. I tried to check this by having my app service hosted in APIM call a dummy function app I had created.  In the dummy function app I logged the header details.

It appeared that the IP coming through was that of the app service and not the APIM instance.  I was expecting (and hoping) it to be the APIM IP

Answer (score 1):

See on APIM overview page, public IP will be visible in the top section

Answer (score 0):

APIM is only a gateway in front of app service. It is not a host environment for app service. So if you call 3rd party services from within the app service, the IP of the caller will always be the app service. It won't be the IP of APIM. Actually the call won't go through APIM at all.